# How to not loose the type of the object in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection called `docs`, and at each new document that is created I need to get its path. Here is the function:

```
exports.onDocCreate = onDocumentCreated("docs/{docId}", (event) => {
  const doc = event.data;
  if (!doc) {
    console.log("No data associated with the event");
    return;
  }
  const docPath = getDocPath(doc);
});
```

And here is the getDocPath function:

```
function getDocPath(doc) {
  const path = doc.ref.path;
  return path;
}
```

In the first function, `doc` is an object of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, but when it is passed to the `getDocPath` functions, it doesn't work as an object of such a type. I cannot call `ref` on the `doc` object, even if [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#ref) is a part of the [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) class.

[image]

How to work in the second function with the `doc` object as a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` object type?

@Pointy It's is a document of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: The message you highlighted says that `path` is "any", not `doc`.

Comment: @Pointy I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I just updated my answer. Can you please take a look?

Comment: What you are describing is impossible. If `doc` contains a reference to a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` object, then that will be the value in the called function. Therefore, I suspect the real problem is that `doc` is *not* a reference to such an object in the calling function.

Comment: @Pointy It is an object pf type `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. Please check the screenshot in my question. How to solve this?

Comment: What matters is the value *at runtime*. JavaScript does not have typed variables; that's either something your IDE is doing, or else you're actually using Typescript.

Comment: Is this question about the Typescript type or about the JavaScript type? Is this about IntelliSense or about the actual code behavior? Where does the type `QueryDocumentSnapshot` come from? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Pointy It's plain JavaScript code in VSC.

Comment: @jabaa It's about JavaScript, not Typescript. About both. The data is an object of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot` that comes from the `event` argument. And `event` is an object of type `FirestoreEvent<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`.

Comment: Your code is pure JavaScript, but the types in your screenshot are TypeScript types. IntelliSense uses TypeScript even for pure JavaScript. Do you have runtime errors?

Comment: VSC can only make type inferences when it has enough information to do so. In the `getDocPath()` function, it has no good way to know what type the `doc` parameter will be; it could be *anything* because JavaScript does not have typed parameters.

Comment: @Pointy The issue is that in the first function I can use the object correctly, and call the corresponding fields, while in the second function, I cannot, using the exact same object that was passed as an argument.

Comment: What error message do you get? What does it even mean to loose the type in JavaScript? Where do you read the type in your code?

Comment: JavaScript is not a typed language.  VSCode can simulate types if it sees other type information available from sources like JSDoc comments or TypeScript code, but it it just can't force types.  The best you can't do is provide type hints.  It sounds like you want a type hint for the arguments of your `getDocPath` function.  JSDoc has a way to do this. Check the other question that answers this more generally.

Comment: Unfortunately, JS is not a type-safe language. One thing you can do is to the use an if-else statement before accessing the object with `typeof`. For example, if you wanted to make sure an object was a string before accessing it, consider wrapping it in the following statement: `if (typeof someVar == "string") { ... }`. The IDE will now treat `someVar` as a string and autocomplete will be reenabled. With custom types, this may be problematic depending on the IDE you're using. You may need to look for IDE plugins that can improve autocomplete for custom types in such cases.

Comment: @jabaa there is no error to report. The OP's problem is enforcing type safety in JavaScript. "Losing type" is simply referring to the IDE not recognizing the type of the object. The OP wants to be able to assign a type to an object throughout so that the IDE can offer up autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: @trndjc If we're talking about TypeScript and IntelliSense, the title, tags and description are wrong and should be fixed. The whole question in its current state doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @jabaa the question is tagged JavaScript, not TypeScript, and the code in question is also JavaScript, not TypeScript. There is no TypeScript in this question. And the question makes perfect sense if you understand the problem.

Comment: @trndjc I understand the question. The code works. The JavaScript is correct. The types are TypeScript types inferred by IntelliSense. There is no type-specific code in this JavaScript code. The JavaScript code doesn't loose the types. IntelliSense looses the types. You can still access the properties in the JavaScript code. The OP wrote _"JavaScript looses types"_ and _"I cannot call `ref` on the `doc` object"_. That's wrong and doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jabaa When I deploy the function, I get an error message that says that `path` is undefined. The path is just a string that points to the document.

Comment: @trndjc Thank you so much for the information and patience. It seems to me that you really understood my problem. I've learned important things.

Comment: In that case the dupe target is wrong. You don't want to set the type of the function parameter. You have an actual bug in your code. How did IntelliSense solve the bug?

Comment: @jabaa No, I'll try to change the IDE, because instead of helping, it causes more confusion. Thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: _"When I deploy the function, I get an error message that says that `path` is undefined."_ That is an actual bug in your code, not a problem with IDE setting. That has nothing to do with the typings in IntelliSense. You have fix your code or data.